# What is the recommended method to i18n XSL files in a java struts project?

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, internationalization, apache-fop

I'm currently working to i18n an application. In this application, we are using Struts and the JSTL library to externalized hard-coded text.

The majority of the text in this application is externalized except for some XSL (used to generate PDF). I would like to externalize all the hard-coded text from these XSL into the bundles I had already created. One of my constraints : all translatable text have to be regroup in few properties files.

Is it possible to use something like the FMT tag system ?
Or there is some default or recommended Java/XML mechanism ?
Or should I have to create a bean used as resource that will be able to find text in bundles ?

Thanks in advance

**Second entry**

By going deeper in the code I found that PDFs are generated through Apache FOP. I will try to adapt [this tutorial](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200409/CreatingMultipleLanguagePDFusingApacheFOP.html) to the project I am working on.

If anyone had more ideas, especially on how use the resources bundles instead of that Lang.xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally decided to to use some built-in fonctionalities of the FOP API.

As the Apache FOP API for Java use Sax, i can pass java object to the parsed XSL. I just had to had this line :`transformer.setParameter("translater", new MyTranslater());` before to use my transformer (MyTranslater has a method called  `getTranslattedText(String key)`, This method is able to retrieve some text from the bundles at the condition that the key is in them).

Then I had to add 2 things :

- the corresponding namespace in the first tag of the XSL file `xmlns:i18n="java:com.mypackage.of.MyTranslater"`
- the parameter by adding `<xsl:param name="translater" />` in the first lines of the document

Finally, to use my translater parameter, I just had to writ :
`<xsl:value-of select="i18n:getTranslattedText($translater, 'one.random.key')" />`